# The vertical lines of my table does not show correctly

Tags: latex

I'm working on overleaf and when I use the package **multirow** the vertical lines of my table are shown incorrectly. Below I post my code and an image of the table.

Thanks!!

```
\begin{table}[H] 
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| p{5cm}| p{9cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{5cm}{ \textbf{Models}}    & \multirow{2}{9cm}{\textbf{Descripció}} \\ \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{5cm}{Models clàssics }                    & \multirow{3}{9cm}{Inclouen els tres més citats: booleà, espai vectorial y probabilístic} \\ \\ \\\hline
        \multirow{3}{5cm}{Models alternatius}                 & \multirow{3}{9cm}{Estan basats en la Lògica Fuzzy} \\ \\ \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{5cm}{Models lògics}                      & \multirow{3}{9cm}{Basats en la Lògica Formal. La recuperació de informació es un proces inferèncial.} \\ \\ \\\hline
       \multirow{4}{5cm}{ Models basats en la interactivitat} & \multirow{4}{9cm}{Inclouen possibilitats de expansió del alcans de la búsqueda i fan us de retroalimentació por la rellevància de los documents recuperats.} \\ \\ \\ \\
       \hline
        \multirow{4}{5cm}{Models basats en IA }               &  \multirow{4}{9cm}{Bases de coneixements, xarxes neuronals, algoritmes genètics y processaments del llenguatge natural.}\\ \\ \\ \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Classificació dels Models de Recuperació de Informació segons
    Dominich. Fuente: Dominich, S. ‘A unified mathematical definition of classical
    information retrieval’. Journal of the American Society for Information Science,
    51 (7), 2000. p. 614-624.}
    \label{tab:Classificació dels Models.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: table with wrong vertical lines]

Answer (score 1):

#### Preface:

Don't use vertical lines in tables.

(have a look at https://wiert.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/zy8dkpa.gif for some tips on professional looking tables)

---

That being said, your problem is that all your rows must have the same number of cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| p{5cm}| p{9cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{5cm}{ \textbf{Models}}    & \multirow{2}{9cm}{\textbf{Descripció}} \\ & \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{5cm}{Models clàssics }                    & \multirow{3}{9cm}{Inclouen els tres més citats: booleà, espai vectorial y probabilístic} \\& \\ & \\\hline
        \multirow{3}{5cm}{Models alternatius}                 & \multirow{3}{9cm}{Estan basats en la Lògica Fuzzy} \\& \\ & \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{5cm}{Models lògics}                      & \multirow{3}{9cm}{Basats en la Lògica Formal. La recuperació de informació es un proces inferèncial.} \\& \\  &\\\hline
       \multirow{4}{5cm}{ Models basats en la interactivitat} & \multirow{4}{9cm}{Inclouen possibilitats de expansió del alcans de la búsqueda i fan us de retroalimentació por la rellevància de los documents recuperats.} \\ &\\ & \\  &\\
       \hline
        \multirow{4}{5cm}{Models basats en IA }               &  \multirow{4}{9cm}{Bases de coneixements, xarxes neuronals, algoritmes genètics y processaments del llenguatge natural.}\\  &\\ &\\ &\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Classificació dels Models de Recuperació de Informació segons
    Dominich. Fuente: Dominich, S. ‘A unified mathematical definition of classical
    information retrieval’. Journal of the American Society for Information Science,
    51 (7), 2000. p. 614-624.}
    \label{tab:Classificació dels Models.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, instead of manually adding all these unnecessary extra rows, I would just increase the row sep. This is particularly easy with the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp] 
\centering
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=10pt}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={QX[h]},row{1}={font=\bfseries},hlines,vlines}
        Models & Descripció \\
        Models clàssics & Inclouen els tres més citats: booleà, espai vectorial y probabilístic  \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Classificació dels Models de Recuperació de Informació segons
    Dominich. Fuente: Dominich, S. ‘A unified mathematical definition of classical
    information retrieval’. Journal of the American Society for Information Science,
    51 (7), 2000. p. 614-624.}
    \label{tab:Classificació dels Models.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]